# Growth of products of large sets in Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lattices, additive-combinatorics

The Steinhaus Theorem states that if $A$ is a set of positive measure in a locally compact group $G$, then the set $A *A^{-1} := \{ab^{-1} | a,b \in A \}$ contains a ball around the identity in $G$.

I am in need of an effective version of this fact for certain infinite Lie groups $G$ (say $SL_3(\mathbb{R})$ and its lattices).

The precise statement I would like is as follows: Let $B_n$ be a ball of radius $n$ in $G$ (or a lattice) and suppose there exists subset $S_n$ of $B_n$ such that $S_n$ and $B_n$ have more or less equal mass, meaning that:

$$\frac{vol(B_n \setminus S_n)}{vol(B_n)} < a_n $$ for a certain sequence $a_n$ that is decreasing to zero.

My question is whether there exists an integer $k$ and $\delta > 0 $ such that for $n$ large:

$B_{\delta n} \subset S_n*S_n*\stackrel{k}{\cdots}*S_n $

Observe that the question depends on how fast $a_n$ is decreasing and also in the type of group $G$ is, for example if $G$ abelian, $a_n$ can be just a small constant.  Also, it is not hard to see that for any $G$ the result holds if $a_n$ decreases exp. fast.

So the real question is how fast $a_n$ has to decrease to zero in order for this statement to hold. I'm mostly interested in the case $G= SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, $G = SL_3(\mathbb{R})$, or its lattices, in those cases, can $a_n$ decrease slightly slower than exp. fast?

Any information related or kind of related to this type of questions would be greatly appreciated.